# Calculate number of days between 2 dates with custom rules

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

This are the rules:

- Every month have 30 days (including February).
- Years have 360 days.

Here is one example:

- **Initial Date**: 2/2/10
- **End Date**: 8/21/12

The calculation of days would be:

- *2/2/10 to 2/1/11* = **360** days
- *2/2/11 to 2/1/12* = **360** days
- *2/2/12 to 8/21/12* = **200** days

The last 200 days are calculated the following way:

- 2/2/12 to 8/1/12 = 180 days (6 months)
- 8/2/12 to 8/21/12 = 20 days

Total would be **920 days**

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Where to begin to create a formula to calculate the number of days.

Comment: You already have a formula, because you already did the calculation for the example dates shown in your question...

Comment: Have a look at momentjs.com, if you haven't.

Comment: Can you customise moment.js to handle 30 day months?

Comment: Implement that formula to php. I see that there is a date_diff formula that can help me with that.

Comment: could you please specify in which lang you will require formula? php or javascript.

Comment: what is the exact issue nad in which platform it is js/php,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, this is what I ended up using:

```
$iDate = Carbon::createFromDate(2010, 2, 2);
$eDate = Carbon::createFromDate(2012, 8, 21);

$dateDiff = date_diff($iDate, $eDate);

$date = 0;
$date += $dateDiff->y * 360;
$date += $dateDiff->m * 30;
$date += $dateDiff->d + 1; // Need to add one more day

dd($date); // Outputs 920
```

This is using Laravel which has the Carbon package included.

Answer (score 0):

```
//2/2/10 to 2/1/11 = 360 days
$date_1 = "2/2/10";
$date_2 = "2/1/11";
$differenceFormat = "%a";
$diff = dateDifference($date_1 , $date_2 , $differenceFormat)   ;
echo "<br/>";
echo "$date_1 to $date_2 = $diff days";

//2/2/11 to 2/1/12 = 360 days
$date_1 = "2/2/11";
$date_2 = "2/1/12";
$differenceFormat = "%a";
$diff = dateDifference($date_1 , $date_2 , $differenceFormat)   ;
echo "<br/>";
echo "$date_1 to $date_2 = $diff days";

//2/2/12 to 8/21/12 = 200 days
$date_1 = "2/2/12";
$date_2 = "8/21/12";
$differenceFormat = "%a";
$diff = dateDifference($date_1 , $date_2 , $differenceFormat)   ;
echo "<br/>";
echo "$date_1 to $date_2 = $diff days";
//final
$date_1 = "2/2/10";
$date_2 = "8/21/12";
$differenceFormat = "%a";
$diff = dateDifference($date_1 , $date_2 , $differenceFormat)   ;
echo "<br/>";
echo "$date_1 to $date_2 = $diff days";
function dateDifference($date_1 , $date_2 , $differenceFormat = '%a' )
{
    $datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    return $interval->format($differenceFormat);

}
```